# Python 3.3 with numpy error under ubuntu 12.04

Tags: numpy, ubuntu-12.04, python-3.3

I'm quite forced to use python 3.3 in this moment, but I have an error every time I want to load the numpy library. The error is as follows:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Numpy is working fine with python 3.2, but for some reason here it gets all ugly. 
One of the approaches I did was to comment the *from . import multiarray* but it trew another error. Maybe someone has already had this problem. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: How did you install numpy?

Comment: from the repositories with `apt-get install python3-numpy`. The thing is that python3 is usually an alias for python3.2 (or at least in my case), in python3.2 is working well, however, for python 3.3 the sys.path is redirecting to the `python3/dist-packages` directory as you can see in the error message which is the same as for version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it guys. First thing to do is to download the distribute setup and install it with python3.3. That installs easy_install and well. See the short code here:

```
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3.3 -m distribute_setup install
sudo easy_install-3.3 pip
sudo pip3.3 install numpy
```

In the case the last command tells you that you already have numpy, just do:

```
sudo pip3.3 install -U numpy
```

Comment: I think `pip3.3` should be changed in `pip-3.3`.

Comment: I don't know if that's a general thought or is about the syntax. But the syntax is correct, I double checked it.

Comment: It's about the syntax: I run ubuntu 12.04, but `pip3.3` is not recognized. `pip-3.3` is though.

Comment: weird, i'm under the same OS, and it's working that way, anyway, that's good it worked for you ;)